# Using codemirror to execute code on server

Tags: codemirror

Novice to Codemirror.

I have codemirror running on my server I have it set to Python mode. Can someone please suggest how I go about executing the code and showing the result on the page where I have written the python code

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing much about your setup, here's a general idea:

1. Use the [getValue() method](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#getValue) to get the code from your CodeMirror instance.
2. Assuming the code is a run-able Python script, you can either
   **(1)** send the code to your back end with AJAX or a POST request and run it there. Or **(2)** you could run the Python script in the browser with a library like one discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155551/python-in-browser-how-to-choose-between-brython-pypy-js-skulpt-and-transcrypt).
3. If you ran it on the back end, you can send the result of running the code back as text or JSON with your preferred protocol. If you ran it on the browser, you should probably follow the guidelines for the specific library you used.

Comment: Worth mentioning, one does not simply run arbitrary Python code on the server without incurring extremely serious security risks. You'll need to investigate some sort of sandbox environment if there's any chance the website is on the internet or can otherwise be visited by any untrusted entity.